# changing input type submit to <a> tag which must work exactly as input>submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that ends with

```
input type='submit'
```

That is used to submit the form and also trigger validation script.

Now I don't like this submit button. I want submit to be just an  tag but with submit function to trigger validation normally.

Is there any way out of this problem ?

Comment: Can't understand your question. Do you want a button onclick of which validation and submit function will be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
$('.anchor').click(function() {
  $('#form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

it's just like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit(); return false;">Submit</a>
```

or better:

```
<a href="#" class="submit">Submit</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('.submit').click(function(){
      $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
  });
</script>
```

note that this solutions requiore jQuery and will only work if javascript is enabled while the traditional submit-button works everytime.